# How to prove that $\exists \xi\in[a,b],f(\xi)=g(\xi)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be monotonically increasing, $g(x)\in C[a,b]$ and  $f(a)\geqslant g(a)$,$f(b)\leqslant g(b)$.Prove that $\exists \xi\in[a,b],f(\xi)=g(\xi)$.This is a question in our entrance test,if $f(x)\in C[a,b]$, then let $F(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ can solve this problem.But the title doesn't say f is continuous, so I don't know how to start.

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous, the statement is false. Draw a monotonic increasing function $f$ with some jump $c \in (a,b)$ and a continuous function $g$ which cross the jump.

Comment: @PabloHerrera Try to build a concrete example and you will see that that is wrong.

Comment: @PabloHerrera, no, because g rises faster than f and would need to go backwards through the gap. Your suggestion would be true if g could decrease from a to b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $A = \{ x \in [a,b], g(x)\ge f(x)\}$

As $g(b) \ge f(b), $ $b \in A$ so $w =  \inf A$ exists.

Now if $g(w) < f(w)$ we can pick an $ \epsilon >0$ such that $w' \in [w, w+ \epsilon ) \implies g(w') < f(w) $

However that means $w' \in [w, w+ \epsilon ) \implies g(w') < f(w') $ as $f$ is increasing. But this means that $w + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is a lower bound for $A$. This is a contradiction as $w$ is the greatest lower bound.

Alternatively if $g(w) > f(w)$ we can pick an $ \epsilon >0$ such that $w' \in (w- \epsilon, w] \implies g(w') > f(w)$.

But then $w' \in (w- \epsilon, w] \implies g(w') > f(w')$ as $f$ is increasing. This means that $w - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is in $A$. This is a contradiction as $w$ is a lower bound for $A$.

Now we apply trichotomy of order to get that $f(w) = g(w)$

Comment: Thank you,as $g(b)\geqslant f(b)$, that means $k=\sup A$?

Comment: I made a mistake, I used $k$ at the start but $w$ everywhere else, I have fixed that now. To answer your question, in that step I was showing that $A$ is non-empty, and hence, since $A$ is bounded it has a finite least lower bound. $w = \inf A$

Comment: Thank you,as $g(b)\geqslant f(b)$, So we know that $b$ is an upper bound,but a set with a non empty upper bound has upper bound. How can it be explained that it must have a lower bound?

Comment: $g(b) \ge f(b)$ shows that $b \in A$.  We also know that $A \subseteq [a,b]$ and so $A$ is bounded. Any bounded non-empty set has a least lower bound

Comment: Thank you,it's my problem that ignores some basic things

Comment: Do we just need to consider the case of $g(w) > f(w)$?

Comment: I consider the case where $g(w) <f(w)$ in lines 3-5 of my answer and the case $g(w) > f(w)$ in lines 6-8.

Comment: Well, I see, but $x$ belonging to set $A$ should only be $\geqslant$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128007/discussion-between-b-martin-and-hilbert1994).